# Can a website be created with crawl result as contents

Tags: web-crawler

Can we create a website to display crawl results as contents? Lets say new of a particular company. Once the company name is selected, web crawler will crawl latest news related to the company and display results.

Can this be done?

Also can we use Google `AdSense` with such a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. You can create a website to display any content at all really. Also, AdSense can be used on any website, provided you respect the terms and conditions.